# Error while presenting a alert on a MMdrawer right controller by swiping a cell to delete

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

Error: Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior ()

Any thoughts? I guess I am presenting too many controllers in one view, but I can't figure out what I should do.

Your help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
            // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
            let alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Confirmation", message: "Delete this message?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
                (action) -> Void in
                // action
                // delete this notification
                // after delete in server, will refresh table view
                refreshResults()

            }))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
                (action) -> Void in
            }))
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Your problem is likely related to trying to bring up an alert view in the middle of handling the delete action.  If you do not bring up the alert at that point in time does it resolve the issue?  What does the refreshResults call do?

Comment: Sorry, refreshResult should only be executed if click "YES". I guess the problem is somehow related to MMDrawer. After I put this view controller as left controller, this error comes out.